# Geany is not compiling python script, but it runs on terminal

Tags: python3, geany

I installed Anaconda, and I run my scripts on terminal successfully with:

```
python3 scritp.py
```

When I execute on Geany I get:

```
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
```

How to run a python script on Geany as I do on Terminal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should write the full python3 path to execute on Geany, as explained below:

First, on terminal:

```
which python3
```

And you'll get something like:

```
/home/myUser/anaconda3/bin/python3
```

Copy it, open a any python script on Geany, Build>Set Build Commands>Execute Commands>Execute> and substitute `python` by `/home/myUser/anaconda3/bin/python3`

[image]

*(Of course if you are using other python version, the procedure is the same)*

Comment: Not working for me on geany 1.29.